How to make my Header component tracked by react Router while outside of RouterProvider?
I am stuck with a problem that seems simple to solve.
The links inside my Header component don't work:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header className='p-2 flex flex-row justify-between sticky top-0 items-center z-10'>
      <h4>Karbon Tools</h4>
      <ul className='flex flex-row gap-6 items-center'>
        <li>
          <Link to="/login">
            <button className="btn-green">
              Se connecter
            </button>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  )
}

And the issue seems that I already provide a "Router thingy" in my App.tsx file like this:
import router from './routes.tsx'
import { RouterProvider} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header.tsx'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App

Do you now anyway of making react router track my Header components links?
I tried to apply the BrowserRouter in my Header component like this:
// import router from "../routes"

import { Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header className='p-2 flex flex-row justify-between sticky top-0 items-center z-10'>
      <h4>Karbon Tools</h4>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ul className='flex flex-row gap-6 items-center'>
          <li>
            <a href="#" className='link'>Un autre bouton</a>
          </li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/login">
              <button className="btn-green">
                Se connecter
              </button>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </header>
  )
}

but it doesn't work. I tried to put my Header inside the RouterProvider component, but it doesn't work either.
